# Can't setup SubDomain on Linode Server

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, virtualhost, linode

I have bought a server from linode.com and set it up with my purchased domain from namecheap. Setting up the DNS worked as expected and I followed the official documentation from linode.

But whenever I am trying to set up a subdomain in the same server, despite following the same documentation, for some reason I can't set it up.

Here is the config:
Server: Apache on Ubuntu 18.04
Domain: **randomxyz.xyz**

Here are the steps that I followed:

- Created AAAA record in Linode Manager Panel.

```
     IP -> Server IP.
     Hostname -> temp.
```

- SSH into the server.
- created a folder named **temp.randomxyz.xyz** inside **var/www/html**.
- created public_html, log and backups folders for temp.randomxyz.xyz.
- created **temp.randomxyz.xyz.conf** in **etc/apache2/sites-available**
- put Vhost config in the conf file:

```
# domain: randomxyz.xyz
# public: /var/www/html/randomxyz.xyz/public_html/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin ok@randomxyz.xyz
  ServerName  temp.randomxyz.xyz
  ServerAlias temp.randomxyz.xyz

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/temp.randomxyz.xyz/public_html

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/temp.randomxyz.xyz/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/temp.randomxyz.xyz/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- Enable the new configured site: **a2ensite temp.randomxyz.xyz**
- Reload Apache: **systemctl restart apache2**

I have waited for more than 48 hours. The Subdomain is not working.

**What am I missing here?** 
**Do I have to do something in namecheap manager?**

Comment: Also, pinging to the subdomain gives this result:

**Ping request could not find host temp.randomxyz.xyz. Please check the name and try again.**

Comment: Give us the real domain name you're using so we can help.

Comment: Did you add a A record as well? You added a AAAA record, do you have IPv6 connectivity?